# How to execute a SQL query every second and insert output into another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a designing a script to take some data and average it out. I have a MySQL database with two tables, Table 1 contains continuous data from sensor, it is stored as [id, data, timestamp]. Table has the format [id, hasAverage, timestamp].

What I want:

(1) is to every time take 6 values from table 1 and average them
(2) put the average into hasAverage in table 2

For part (1) I have made this SQL query which does the same:

```
SELECT AVG(data) FROM (SELECT data FROM Table1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 6) items;
```

When executed this gives average as output.

For Part (2), how can I put output from table 1 to table 2?

I am using MySQL in Xampp.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an `INSERT INTO <table> ... SELECT ...`, called an [insert-select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) query.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (average)
SELECT AVG(data) FROM (SELECT data FROM Table1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 6) items;
```

Simply replace `average` with whatever column name stores the value in your `table2`.